# How to start CLSIDs from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, rundll32.exe

Some of my shortcuts in Windows are pointing to targets that look like CLSIDs, and I cannot modify the target, it's grayed out. They look *like* this: `{ED228FDF-9EA8-4870-83b1-96b02CFE0D52}` (non-working example).

Is there a way to "start" these CLSIDs directrly from the command line (without using the link), ie. if I know a CLSID, can I start it from the command line, without making a shortcut?

I've tried to start it with XP like `start {ED228FDF-9EA8-4870-83b1-96b02CFE0D52}`, but it gives a "file not found" type of error.

Comment: What are these shortcuts to?

Comment: @Karan my current target is a 'connect to VPN' icon that was created by an installer. But I recall from 9x days that the Recycle bin was accessible this way... actually when I've tried to confirm this, I ran into http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/CLSID-List.htm

Comment: @Karan No, I mean this notation with the `::` prefix actually works with start/run too, not just AHK. And also with `start`. But I wonder why does some of them not work, what is this notation and what does windows actually do? It does *not* work with my VPN starter.

Answer (score 4):

See the [**Canonical Names of Control Panel Items**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330741(v=vs.85).aspx) article for the complete list, grouped according to the Windows version supported. You can even create shortcuts using `explorer /e,::{CLSID}`.

As per [this source](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/explorer/cmdline.htm):

> A shell namespace path may be a file system path but may also refer to class objects by using the notation of two colons followed by a CLSID in curly braces.

The [**IShellFolder** shell interface's **ParseDisplayName** method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775090(v=vs.85).aspx) is responsible for handling "references to items in the [shell] namespace that have a GUID associated with them using the "::{GUID}" syntax".