# Adding Locations to Windows 8 "Send To" Option

Tags: windows-8

I would like to add multiple locations for the send to option when I right click a file. Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[image: Win]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `shell:sendto`, open the folder (i.e. `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`) and add shortcuts to your folder locations.

Comment: Works. Further investigations into these "shell" commands might be fascinating.

Comment: See [this article](http://winaero.com/blog/the-full-list-of-shell-commands-in-windows-8/). [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/585865/138343) and [this article](http://winaero.com/blog/the-most-comprehensive-list-of-shell-locations-in-windows-8/) might also interest you.